# Is there any penalty for using the react app typescript template while barely using typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

We got this react app in javascript and i'm the new chaos monkey assigned to this project, and I prefer typescript to javascript.
If i were to add typescript to this react app and then barely use it. Would any technical issues appear?

Then of course the is the human element to it, and what the other developer thinks. But from a strict technical perspective, would there be any downside to implement typescript alongside javascript?

In my world I could: enable allowJS, disable checkJS in my tsconfig. This would allow both worlds to interact with each other without any technical issues.

Some things will of course be inconvenient, but Typescript is such a nice investment. And the project is not all to big and is still in its early state.

Comment: What is the purpose of typescript is not everything is typed?

Comment: Who would enforce your 500 dabloon penalty for doing this? Jokes aside, no, there's no penalty. Do as you wish, it's your code.

Comment: The this is that the other developer have started this project in javascript. There will be a period of converting and he is not experienced with TS and would probably continue with JS for a while if i were to add TS

Comment: It will increase build/compilation time, but CRA is already dreadfully slow, so I don't think that should matter — it probably won't even be noticeable.

Comment: Great! i'm out of my depths here and just want to make sure. Be damn this javascript sorcery and give me proper types!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> n my world I could: enable allowJS, disable checkJS in my tsconfig. This would allow both worlds to interact with each other without any technical issues

This is what I would do.

> Is there any penalty for using the react app typescript template while barely using typescript

No. The cost is the performance cost of type checking at compile time. TypeScript has one of the cheapest type checking costs out there.